# Why am I getting floats when using pivot_table on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Part of my initial DataFrame (rwy16_df) is:

[image]

When I use:

```
  pivoted = rwy16_df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='count', columns='cloud_range', values='maestro_rate')
```

I get:

[image]

Why do I get decimals?

When I use

```
pivoted = rwy16_df.pivot(index='count', columns='cloud_range', values='maestro_rate')
```

I get the value error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I'm trying to get the unaveraged values into my pivoted dataframe.

Comment: Its averaging the 'maestro_rate' for each cloud_range, that's why its float..

Comment: try reset_index after the pivot operation.

Comment: Thanks @SubbuVidyaSekar I tweaked the question a little as there was a mistake. Are you saying pivoted = rwy16_df.pivot(index='count', columns='cloud_range', values='maestro_rate').reset_index() may work?

Comment: Yes.. no need to reset the index of original dataframe.

Comment: How do I just get the raw values in the df?